# tastypie filter a foreignkey related resource

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship, tastypie

I have a problem that i really can't solve like anyhow.

All i want is, to get from api/epg the channels that have their shows in the range of now and 2 hours later. Somehow i get all the channels with all the shows, not anything in the time range.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

models.py

```
class Channels(models.Model):
    sort_order = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Events(models.Model):

    event_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    channel = models.ForeignKey('Channels', related_name='events')
    start_time = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, null = True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField( blank=True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

api.py

```
class EPGResource(ModelResource):
    events= fields.ToManyField('xyz.api.EventResource','events',  full=True)

    class Meta:
        now = datetime.now()
        later = now + timedelta(hours=2)
        queryset = Channels.objects.filter(events__start_time__range(now,later)).order_by('sort_order')
        resource_name = 'epg'
        filtering = {
          "start_time"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "name"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "events"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "channels": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }



class EventResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Events.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'events'

        filtering = {
          "start_time"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "genre"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "channel": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

Comment: your `filtering` for `EventResource` looks misaligned. Spacing matters: is that just a copy and paste error from your source code to SO? Otherwise make sure to indent `filtering` by 1 more space.

Comment: No, it's just a copy paste error. I've corrected it. With this code, i get output from tastypie, but it lists all events connected to that channel, doesn't filter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you're going to need to do that filter in `get_object_list` as tastypie resources aren't built at runtime:

```
class EPGResource(ModelResource):
    events= fields.ToManyField('xyz.api.EventResource','events',  full=True)

    class Meta:
        now = datetime.now()
        later = now + timedelta(hours=2)
        queryset = Channels.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'epg'
        filtering = {
          "start_time"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "name"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "events"  :   ['exact', 'range'],
          "channels": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        now = datetime.now()
        later = now + timedelta(hours=2)
        return super(EPGResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(events__start_time__range(now,later)).order_by('sort_order')
```

Comment: how harder can this get? i still get events with dates in the past: start_time: "2012-12-30T07:00:00",

Comment: ok, i've installed django_devserver and now i can see sql queries: 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `epg_channels` INNER JOIN `epg_events` ON (`epg_channels`.`id` = `epg_events`.`channel_id`) WHERE `epg_events`.`start_time` BETWEEN 2013-01-03 06:36:39 and 2013-01-03 08:36:39 

This inner join should be right outer join, why it's joining inner?

Comment: No, your query is correct. I'm assuming you're having a localization issue. Try using `utcnow()` instead of `now()`.